# Search "keyword" in a list of txt file in a folder and move txt file to another folder if "keyword" is found (batch scripting)

Tags: batch-file, scripting

**Below is my pseudocode**

```
For loop in a folder where contains a list of txt files
if (keyword is found in the txt file) && (keyword2 is found in the txt file) 
move the txt file to another folder 
log the current txt file name to temp file
```

keyword and keyword2 are not in the same line

How to write as batch script?

Comment: ...yet another one who thinks this site is a free code writing service, but it is not. Please share what you have tried and desribe what specifc problem you are facing. Please learn [ask]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would run it all in the same loop:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Delims=" %%A In (
    'FindStr/IMC:"SecondString" *.log^|FindStr/IMC:"FirstString" /F:/') Do (
    (Echo=%%~fA)>>"TempFile.log"
    Move /Y "%%~fA" "C:\Destination")
Timeout -1
```

Replace `FirstString`, `SecondString` and `C:\Destination` as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

not tested:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%# in (*txt) do (
    set "line1="
    set "line2="
    if "%%~nx#" neq "%~nx0" (
        for /f "tokens=2* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n /i "keyword1" "%%#"') do set line1=%%a
        for /f "tokens=2* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n /i "keyword2" "%%#"') do set line2=%%a

        if defined line1 if defined line2 if "!line1!" neq "!line2!"  (
            echo move /y "%%~f#" "c:\destination"
        )
    )
)
```

In this line `echo move /y "%%~f#" "c:\destination"` you can see which files will be moved. If it's ok remove the `echo` word.